# Не могу получить процент заряда аккумулятора телефона

Tags: java, android

Как в Android узнать данный процент заряда аккумулятора? Вот код, который я использовал:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Info.this.batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
    }

}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

в результате которого значение переменной `batteryLevel` равно 1134231552. Вместо `"level"` я пробовал указывать `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` - результат один и тот же, каждый раз такие странные большие числа. Как исправить ошибку?

---

Так же пробовал получить значение заряда батареи так:

```
Info.this.batteryLevel = (float) intent.getIntExtra("level", -1) / (float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```

результат одинаковый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот линк по которому можно получить информацию по тому как получить информацию о батареи [link](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html)

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо еще запрашивать масштаб:

```
int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```

уровень замеряется как `(float)level/(float)scale`

Comment: Изменил вопрос.